# Apply .htaccess Redirect to ALL Subdirectories to www version of site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

In my main `.htaccess` file in the root of my domain, I have the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
# If missing 'www'
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.com [nc]
# Redirect to 'www' version
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,nc]
# Remove 'index.php' from URL 
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,nc]
```

I then have a separate `.htaccess` file in each directory, also removing the `index.php` from the URL, as shown here in the `/products` directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.example.com/products/ [r=301,nc]
```

When I (after clearing my cache) visit `example.com` I am redirected to `www.example.com/`as expected.

But if I type `example.com/products` in my address bar, the page loads as `example.com/products/` and I am **NOT** redirected to the `www.example.com/products/` version.  What am I doing wrong? Please help... and I can provide a better explaination/examples if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you turn on the rewrite engine in an htaccess in a subdirectory, it excludes all rewrite rules that may be in htaccess files in any of its parent directories unless you use the:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
```

directive in the htaccess file in your subdirectories. Since the only rule you have in `/products` only has the redirect for `index.php`, unless the request is for `/products/index.php`, no rules will get applied because the rules in the parent directory are ignored.

Also note that in Apache 2.2, the `inherit` option places the parent's rewrite rules **after** the rules that are in the subdirectory.

---

EDIT:

The inherited rules doesn't work because the base isn't the same. You'll just need to add the redirect to www rules everywhere else as well. So add these to your htaccess file in your `/products/` directory:

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/products/$1 [R=301,nc]
```

---

Alternatively, you can keep the `RewriteOptions inherit` but change your htaccess rule in your document root from:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,nc]
```

to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,nc]
```

Comment: Ok... so if I want all URLs in the root and subdirectories to redirect to their `www` version, AND I want the `index.php` removed from all URLs, what should I put in the `/products/.htaccess` ?

Comment: @AdamD exactly what I said in my answer. `RewriteOptions inherit`. Was that not clear enough?

Comment: Oh ok... so I just want `RewriteOptions inherit` and remove everything else? (Just want to be sure b/c the site is currently live) :)

Comment: @AdamD No, you want the rules you have already, the reason why the rules in the parent directory aren't being applied (the ones that redirect to www) is because you need to add that directive to *also inherit the rules from the parent htaccess*.

Comment: Ok.. so problem - When I inserted `RewriteOptions inherit`, my `/products/` directory redirected to my homepage in the root.  So what's the fix?

Comment: So is there a way to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: @AdamD Yeah, you'll just need to duplicate the redirects everywhere, or just have a single htaccess file in your document root to handle it all.

Comment: I tried out your EDIT... it does not remove the `index.php` from the end of the URL if someone were to type in `example.com/products/index.php`. Is there a way to do both (redirect to the `www` and remove the `index.php`?

Comment: @AdamD don't remove any rules that you already have. The answer says "So **add** these to your htaccess file"

Comment: One more question about your final answer.... On the final RewriteRule where you have the `REQUEST_URI`, what is that actually doing? And what does that take the place of?

Comment: @AdamD It's a bit complicated to explain within a comment. The `RewriteOptions inherit` just literally takes the rules in the parent htaccess and places them as if they're at the end of your `/products/` htaccess file. The problem is the `$1` is not the same as in the parent directory, so you want to use the `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable instead (which includes the subdirectory's pathname, `/products/`) instead of the backreference `$1` which only matches the subdirectory's path (minus the `/products/` part).